# Custom View in tab bar does no longer work in iOS6

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, uinavigationbar, ios6

I have a custom View (`UILabel` + `UIImage`) which I use as the custom view of my `UINavigationController` which I set like so:

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = self.myTitleLabel;
```

This works fine in iOS 5 but ceases to work under iOS 6. Although the value is set in the debugger, it does not show at all.

**Update:** As mark pointed out the docs states the following:

> If this property value is `nil`, the navigation item’s title is displayed in the center of the navigation bar when the receiver is the top item. If you set this property to a custom title, it is displayed instead of the title. This property is ignored if `leftBarButtonItem` is not `nil`.

Now I have a `backButton` and not an "explicit" `leftBarButtonItem`. But what if you want your Logo in the Navigation Bar and still have a Back button *or*  a bar on the left?

Comment: According to the docs: "This property is ignored if leftBarButtonItem is not nil." Are you using a leftBarButtonItem?

Comment: Similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12568504/custom-navigationitem-button-with-qlpreviewcontroller-in-ios6

Comment: No, I have a back button there.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this way before but it seems me like some workaround. I advice you to use your own UIToolBar and hide navigation bar. It's simple. The only what you need is to get image for Back button here http://www.teehanlax.com/downloads/ios-5-gui-psd-iphone-4s/.