# How to get subviews of UIButtonBarStackView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, augmented-reality, quicklook

I am trying to get the subviews of UIButtonBarStackView, so that I can find the right bar button and disable it. I am trying to hide share button in QLPreviewController with usdz files. I have subclassed QLPreviewController and I have this code in viewDidAppear. I can get the subviews till this point and these subviews of StackView returns empty array. Here is my code -

```
UINavigationController *navController = self.childViewControllers.firstObject;
for(UIView *toolbar in navController.view.subviews[2].subviews) {
    if ([NSStringFromClass([toolbar class]) containsString:@"ContentView"]){
        for(UIView * stackView in toolbar.subviews) {
            if ([stackView isKindOfClass:[UIStackView class]]) {
                //StackView subview is empty.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This stack overflow answer might point you in the right direction: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12719382/4102523

Comment: This works brilliantly in normal QuickLook, but with AR Quicklook seems to have UIToolbarContainerView and UIButtonBarStackView. When I try getting the subviews of UIStackView, I am getting empty array. For that matter, I couldn't find any of those bar button or custom view (not sure) items like close, object/AR segment controller and share button. Seems to appear magically..